# Protractor e2e test not recognizing change in navbar after log in

Tags: angular, protractor, google-oauth

When running an e2e test, the test involves the computer logging in with a given email and password using the google login API. Once logged in, the navbar changes saying Login to Logout. I am trying to wait in my test case until the Logout appears, but protractor never recognizes it, even though I see it when I run the test.

I switched the wait to the home-icon which is always displayed in the navbar and the test case passes.

I also added some code to see if it could click the logout button and that works. So now I am very confused why browser.wait never resolves for logout.

navbar.component.html (partial)

```html
  <ul fxLayout fxLayoutGap="20px" class="navigation-items">
        <li>
          <a routerLink='/'>
            <mat-icon id="home-icon" class="icon">home</mat-icon>
            <span class="label">Home</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <mat-icon id="input-icon" class="icon">account_circle</mat-icon>
            <div *ngIf="auth.user$ | async; then user else guest"></div>
            <ng-template #user>
              <span class="label" id="logout" (click)="auth.signOut()">Logout</span>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template #guest>
              <span class="label" id="login" (click)="auth.googleSignin()">Login</span>
            </ng-template>
          </a>
        </li>

   </ul>
```

test case

```
describe('Student Component e2e tests', () => {
  const ec = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  const BROWSER_WAIT = 5000;

  beforeAll(() => {
    this.signInButton.click();
    this.loginToGoogle();
    // browser.sleep(5000);
    // element(by.id('logout')).click(); // able to click logout button
    // browser.sleep(5000);
    browser.wait(ec.visibilityOf(element(by.id('logout'))), 
  BROWSER_WAIT);
  });

  it('should find Logout button', () => {
    expect(element(by.id('logout')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I expect the output to return with no errors, but the actual output returns a time out error.

To recreate clone the repository
https://github.com/ChadwickSchool/Weight-Lifting-App/tree/logout-test-error

Then run the commands

```
git checkout logout-test-error
npm install
ng e2e
```

Comment: Could you add the third parameter to the browser.wait and see if it is logged like so `browser.wait(ec.visibilityOf(element(by.id('logout'))), 
  BROWSER_WAIT, 'timed out waiting for logout button to appear');`

Comment: @DublinDev thank you so much for the idea. It's actually not printing out the error message. it prints a global timeout error

`- Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds`

But when you comment out the browser.wait and test for the home-icon, the test passes. When you add back in the browser.wait for the logout button, the test for the home-icon fails with the above error message. Very strange

Comment: This is one strange alright. browser.wait causing an angular timeout but the actual element interaction works correctly in the expect.... hmm. For interest could you try moving the browser.wait into the it block instead of the beforeAll.

Comment: Yeah we get the same global timeout error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure exactly what fixed it but when we refactored the code to use ng-container, it started to work. The new navbar component looks like:

```html
<div fxFlex fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="flex-end" fxHide.xs>
    <ul fxLayout fxLayoutGap="20px" class="navigation-items">
      <ng-container *ngIf="auth.user$ | async as user; else guest">
        <li>
          <a>
            <div *ngIf="user.isAdmin; then adminhome; else studenthome"></div>
            <ng-template #adminhome>
              <a routerLink="/admin-home" id="home">
                <mat-icon id="home-icon" class="icon">home</mat-icon>
                <span class="label">Home</span>
              </a>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template #studenthome>
              <a routerLink="/student-home" id="home">
                <mat-icon id="home-icon" class="icon">home</mat-icon>
                <span class="label">Home</span>
              </a>
            </ng-template>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <div *ngIf="user.isAdmin; then adminview"></div>
            <ng-template #adminview>
              <a routerLink="/student-list">
                <mat-icon id="history-icon" class="icon">view_list</mat-icon>
                <span class="label" id="history-label">Student's Workout History</span>
              </a>
            </ng-template>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <mat-icon id="dashboard-icon" class="icon">fitness_center</mat-icon>
            <div *ngIf="user.isAdmin; then admin; else student"></div>
            <ng-template #admin>
              <a routerLink="/today-workout-admin">
                <span id="create-workout" class="label">Create Workout</span>
              </a>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template #student>
              <a routerLink="/today-workout-student">
                <span id="workout-label" class="label">Today's Workout</span>
              </a>
            </ng-template>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <mat-icon id="input-icon" class="icon">account_circle</mat-icon>
            <span class="label" id="logout" (click)="auth.signOut()"
              >Logout</span
            >
          </a>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #guest>
        <li>
          <a>
            <mat-icon id="input-icon" class="icon">account_circle</mat-icon>
            <span class="label" id="login" (click)="auth.googleSignin()"
              >Login</span
            >
          </a>
        </li>
      </ng-template>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

The full component is here: 
https://github.com/ChadwickSchool/Weight-Lifting-App/tree/development/src/app/navigation/navbar

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur because Protractor is not resolving promise in browser.wait(ec.visibilityOf(element(by.id('logout'))).
Why? Most likely because the login form is not Angular so Protractor tries to synchronize with it but never happens to. Tests are working when you remove browser.wait(ec.visibilityOf... because there is not dangling promise.
Try to use browser.ignoreSynchronization=true before opening the login form and browser.ignoreSynchronization=false after your last wait (browser.sleep(5000))

Comment: Thanks for the response. We utilize `browser.waitForAngularEnabled` in our `loginToGoogle` function. We use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` at the top of the function and use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)` at the end of the function. When we take `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)` out of loginToGoogle and put it above the 'browser.wait` we get the error "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined"

Comment: @J.D.DeVaughn-Brown can you please provide the code? Also I'm curious why need to take the browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true) out of loginToGoogle function? The structure that you have described above totally make sense: you turn off you synchronization then do your stuff and turn on synchronization to be able to move on

Comment: Here is the link to the full test file. https://github.com/ChadwickSchool/Weight-Lifting-App/blob/logout-test-error/e2e/src/student.component.e2e-spec.ts

Comment: @J.D.DeVaughn-Brown sorry for the late response. The repo is not available anymore but please try to wrap the 'igonre sychronization' in 'then' block after you performing the last action (I far as I remember it was clicking on the 'Next' button)